# Netstat prevented my slowdown?

Tags: linux, debian, netstat

I was wondering what netstat does? I know this kind of a weird question.... We were encountering a very grave slowdown in our web server machine which is running on debian linux.
After running netstat command, for some reason, the web server suddenly performed properly and the slowdown was gone. would netstat have any involvement in this? I know this is kind of weird question but in any case anyone can provide any insight, it would be welcome

Thanks

Comment: 99.9% chance this was just a coincidence. Only thing that netstat *may* have done is done DNS lookups. Other than that, its just formatting information read from `/proc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netstat does not do anything except display list of the network connections,
chances are the network problem are already resolved itself before the netstat command is issued

If you are using database, check the database log
If your website using external resources, check the external resources are running properly

And check is there spike of traffic during that period

Answer (score 1):

netstat simply prints out a wide variety of networking information ranging from interface statistics, routing tables and general connection information. Although a "grave slowdown" is pretty ambiguous, I'm assuming you meant that your server high went through a period of high bandwidth utilization. I don't see anyway possible that running a vanilla plain "netstat" command would have fixed your bandwidth issue, and it just happened to be a coincidence of timing.

In order to provide clear, immediate information and historical tracking for use when solving this bandwidth related problem, I highly suggest you install something like bandwidthd, (http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/) which will provide clear visual indications of how, what, and when network traffic congestion is occuring on your server!

Comment: I would also suggest you take a look at the various sections of useful information provided by the `top` command to make sure that your slowdown is not a resource starvation issue and completely unrelated to bandwidth. You might be surprised!